# Is there a way to use a GROUP BY statement using multiple columns as the new primary key? (NOT one after the other)

Tags: group-by, aggregate

For example, i have tables set up as follows;

```
course_sections
    section_id
    course_number
    section
    term_id
    year
    professor
    capacity

term
    term_id
    term (Fall, Winter, Spring)
    year
```

My current query i am trying is as follows:

```
SELECT cs.professor as 'Professor Name',t.year as 'Year',t.term as 'Term',sum(cs.capacity) as 'Teaching Capacity'
FROM course_sections cs
    JOIN term t ON cs.term_id = t.term_id
GROUP BY cs.professor
ORDER BY cs.professor;
```

The reason I am stuck is because This returns each teachers name one time, and one of the semesters student capacity like follows.

```
NAME      TERM    YEAR    STUDENT CAPACITY
Josh      Fall    2016    150 
Courtney  Fall    2016    150
Steve     Fall    2016    150
```

I need to be able to show it like this

```
NAME       TERM    YEAR    STUDENT CAPACITY
Josh       Fall    2016    75 
Josh       Winter  2017    75 
Courtney   Fall    2016    60 
Courtney   Winter  2017    80 
Steve      Fall    2016    100 
Steve      Winter  2017    50
```

Answer (score 0):

Not very clear on your question, but according to your expected output, you'll need to

*GROUP BY cs.professor, cs.term_id*

to get the student capacity for each professor per term.